# How do I run a machine learning training in the background?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, subprocess

I have a function in Support Vector Classifier which runs on a scheduler on Google Cloud Platform. That function, fetches the new data, adds it to the original data, trains the model on new data and saves it on google cloud storage. All of this takes 5 min to complete. I wish to not wait for the final output, instead I want to run it in the background and end the process without waiting.

Below is my function with comments:

```
def train_model():
    users, tasks, tags, task_tags, task_user, boards = connect_postgres()  ##loading the data from a postgres function
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
    blob = bucket.blob('original_data.pkl')
    pickle_in0 = blob.download_as_string()
    data = pickle.loads(pickle_in0)

    tasks = tasks.rename(columns={'id': 'task_id', 'name': 'task_name'})

    # Joining tasks and task_user_assigns tables
    tasks = tasks[tasks.task_name.isnull() == False]
    task_user = task_user[['id', 'task_id', 'user_id']].rename(columns={'id': 'task_user_id'})
    task_data = tasks.merge(task_user, on='task_id', how='left')

    # Joining users with the task_data
    users = users[['id', 'email']].rename(columns={'id': 'user_id'})
    users_tasks = task_data.merge(users, on='user_id', how='left')
    users_tasks = users_tasks[users_tasks.user_id.isnull() == False].reset_index(drop=True)

    # Joining boards table to user_tasks
    boards = boards[['id', 'name']].rename(columns={'id': 'board_id', 'name': 'board_name'})
    users_board = users_tasks.merge(boards, on='board_id', how='left').reset_index(drop=True)

    # Data Cleaning
    translator = Translator()  # This is to translate if the tasks are not in English
    users_board["task_trans"] = users_board["task_name"].map(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest="en").text)

    users_board['task_trans'] = users_board['task_trans'].apply(lambda x: remove_emoji(x))  #This calls a function to remove Emoticons from text
    users_board['task_trans'] = users_board['task_trans'].apply(lambda x: remove_punct(x))  #This calls a function to remove punctuations from text

    users_board = users_board[['task_id', 'email', 'board_id', 'user_id', 'task_trans']]

    data1 = pd.concat([data, users_board], axis=0)

    df1 = data1.copy

    X = df1.task_trans  #all the observations
    y = df1.user_id  #all the lables

    print(y.nunique())

    #FROM HERE ON, THE TRAINING SCRIPT BEGINS

    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X)
    tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(X_train_counts)
    X_train_transformed = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)

    print('model 1 done')

    labels = LabelEncoder()
    y_train_labels_fit = labels.fit(y)
    y_train_lables_trf = labels.transform(y)

    linear_svc = LinearSVC()
    clf = linear_svc.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train_lables_trf)

    print('model 2 done')

    calibrated_svc = CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=linear_svc, cv="prefit")
    calibrated_svc.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train_lables_trf)

    print('model 3 done')

    # SAVING THE MODELS ON GOOGLE CLOUD STORAGE

    # storage_client = storage.Client()
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-project')

    filename = '~path/svc.sav'
    pickle.dump(calibrated_svc, fs.open(filename, 'wb'))

    filename = '~path/count_vectorizer.sav'
    pickle.dump(count_vect, fs.open(filename, 'wb'))

    filename = '~path/tfidf_vectorizer.sav'
    pickle.dump(tf_transformer, fs.open(filename, 'wb'))

    blob = bucket.blob('original_data.pkl')
    pickle_out = pickle.dumps(df1)
    blob.upload_from_string(pickle_out)

    return "success"
```

Now, I tried to do the following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-c', train_model()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT); print('finished')
```

This also took the same amount of time. Is there a way I can solve this?

Also, if I want to print the python logs for this process on client-side, is that possible?

Comment: `train_model()` **calls the function**.

Comment: Yes, I am not familiar with this. How do I fix this?

Comment: A correct subprocess call would look something like `p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-c', 'from thisfile import train_model; train_model()'])` (possibly still with `stdin` and `stdout` redirected somewhere).